# Removing social networking links from profile fields

Tags: wordpress, hook

I have seen some code online for removing and adding contact fields (via hooks). But there doesn't seem to be any for getting rid of the social network fields you see in WordPress profile sections.

[image]

Here is the code, is there any hook for removing social network fields? I am using a plugin called WP User Frontend and it is pulling these fields in.

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {
    // Add new fields
    $profile_fields['twitter'] = 'Twitter Username';
    $profile_fields['facebook'] = 'Facebook URL';
    $profile_fields['gplus'] = 'Google+ URL';

    // Remove old fields
    unset($profile_fields['google']);

    return $profile_fields;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
```

Comment: These fields are not part of the core, so they must be added by a plugin. Try to search your plugins or themes for one of the networks and if you now the filter that adds these infos, you can use `remove_filter` to disable them http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a very simple plugin that will wait for other plugins to be loaded, then use the function [`remove_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) that [pfefferle mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848207/removing-social-networking-links-from-profile-fields-in-wordpress#comment33072121_21848207) to remove the hook added by the other plugin.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SO) Remove WP User Frontend contact methods
 */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_custom_user_contact_methods' );

function remove_custom_user_contact_methods()
{
    remove_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods' );
}
```